# Getting the coordinates of a Matplotlib annotation label in figure coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to know the coordinates of the bounding rectangle of a text annotation to a Matplotlib plot in figure fraction coordinates. However, when I try to access the "extents" of the patch associated with the annotation, I get `Bbox(x0=-0.33, y0=-0.33, x1=1.33, y1=1.33)` regardless of the size of the text label. These coordinates seem to be associated with an `IdentityTransform`, but don't transform into any meaningful figure fraction coordinates.
How can I obtain the label's coordinates (ideally, lower left corner and upper right corner) in figure fraction units?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return 10 * np.sin(3*x)**4

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = f(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

xpt = 1.75
ypt = f(xpt)
xy = ax.transData.transform([xpt, ypt])
xy = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform(xy)

xytext = xy + [0.1, -0.1]
rdx, rdy = 0, 1
ann = ax.annotate('A point', xy=xy, xycoords='figure fraction',
             xytext=xytext, textcoords='figure fraction',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle="arc3",
                             relpos=(rdx, rdy)),
             bbox=dict(fc='gray', edgecolor='k', alpha=0.5),
             ha='left', va='top'
            )
```

[image]

```
patch = ann.get_bbox_patch()
print(patch.get_extents())
```

gives:

```
[[-0.33 -0.33]
 [ 1.33  1.33]]

c = patch.get_transform().transform(patch.get_extents())
print(c)
```

gives:

```
[[-211.2 -158.4]
 [ 851.2  638.4]]
```

Presumably these are display coordinates, but they don't correspond to the position and size of the label I want the properties of.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before the figure is drawn, the bounding box of a `text` object contains just the coordinates of the box relative to the text inside.

**Therefore it is necessary to draw the figure first and then access the bounding box.**

```
fig.canvas.draw() 
patch = ann.get_bbox_patch()
box  = patch.get_extents()
print box
#prints: Bbox(x0=263.6, y0=191.612085684, x1=320.15, y1=213.412085684)
```

Since those are the coordinates of the box in display units, they need to be tranformed to figure units

```
tcbox = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform(box)
print tcbox
#prints [[ 0.411875    0.39919185]
#        [ 0.50023438  0.44460851]]

# The format is 
#        [[ left    bottom]
#         [ right   top   ]]
```

This returns the bounding box in figure units (ranging from 0 to 1) of the rectangle around the text.

If instead, axes coordinates are desired, it would be

```
ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(box)
```

or if data coordinates are needed,

```
ax.transData.inverted().transform(box)
```

---

If instead the bounding box of the text itself is what's beeing asked for one can use the `get_window_extent()` method of `matplotlib.text.Text` and supply the annotation object as argument. Using

```
box = matplotlib.text.Text.get_window_extent(ann)
print box
# prints Bbox(x0=268.0, y0=196.012085684, x1=315.75, y1=209.012085684)
```

one can proceed as above to obtain the box in figure units.

Comment: Thank you – I have a problem though: I can only reproduce the correct bbox coordinates after `plt.show()`: it isn't enough to call `fig.canvas.draw()`... is this a backend issue? I'm on OS X.

Comment: Since I have no experience whatsoever with Macs, I can only say that this method works in matplotlib 1.5 under Windows with backends `agg`, `TkAgg` and `Qt4Agg`.

Comment: Yup – it's a bug in the Mac OS X backend. Works fine with `agg`. Thanks for your help.