# Getting the coordinates of the arrow in a Matplotlib annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following on from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267733/getting-the-coordinates-of-a-matplotlib-annotation-label-in-figure-coordinates) I have the coordinates of the text label box in figure fraction coordinates and attempted to get the coordinates of the arrow patch in the same way.

But the coordinates I get do not correspond to the arrow, because when I plot a line over the same coordinates it doesn't lie on top of it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return 10 * np.sin(3*x)**4

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = f(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

xpt = 1.75
ypt = f(xpt)
xy = ax.transData.transform([xpt, ypt])
xy = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform(xy)

xytext = xy + [0.1, -0.1]
rdx, rdy = 0, 1
ann = ax.annotate('A point', xy=xy, xycoords='figure fraction',
             xytext=xytext, textcoords='figure fraction',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle="arc3",
                             relpos=(rdx, rdy)),
             bbox=dict(fc='gray', edgecolor='k', alpha=0.5),
             ha='left', va='top'
            )
fig.canvas.draw()

leader_line_box = ann.arrow_patch.get_extents()
print(leader_line_box)
leader_line_box = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform(leader_line_box) 
print(leader_line_box)

from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
line = Line2D(leader_line_box.T[0], leader_line_box.T[1],transform=fig.transFigure, lw=2, color='m')
ax.add_line(line)

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

[image]

How can I get the `((x0,y0), (x1,y1))` coordinates of the annotation arrow in figure fraction units and what has gone wrong in my attempt here?

Comment: I think it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do: plotting a line from bottom left to top right of the arrow bounding box. If you want the line aligned with the arrow you can just put `[::-1]` to reverse either xdata or ydata. Are those not the coordinates you were looking for? Where do you want the line to be plotted?

Comment: Hmm – I guess you're right. What I really want are the coordinates of the tail and the head of the arrow itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way in this very specific case is to just draw the x-coordinates in reverse

```
line = Line2D(leader_line_box.T[0][::-1], leader_line_box.T[1],transform=fig.transFigure, lw=2, color='m')
```

If you need a more general solution,

```
verts = ann.arrow_patch.get_path()._vertices
tverts= fig.transFigure.inverted().transform(verts)  
index = [0,2]
line = Line2D([tverts[index[0],0],tverts[index[1],0]], [tverts[index[0],1],tverts[index[1],1]],
              transform=fig.transFigure, lw=2, color='m')
ax.add_line(line)
```

This will work for any arrow direction (pointing upwards or downwards, east or west) but is specific to the `arrowprops` arguments `arrowstyle='->'` and `connectionstyle="arc3"`. Using different arrowstyle or connection style will require to set `index` to different values which can be found by chosing the appropriate indices from the array stored in `verts`.

---

In a very general case one can also look at the following:

```
box = ann.arrow_patch._posA_posB
tbox = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform(leader_line_box)
print tbox
line = Line2D(tbox.T[0], tbox.T[1],transform=fig.transFigure)
```

However this will get you the line between the annotated point and the text itself. In general this line might be different from the actual arrow, depending in the arrow style in use.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, you have the coordinates of the bounding box of the arrow, which is the box drawn using the arrow as the diagonal. From that, we can find the head / tail coordinates.

The bounding box coordinates are given in the order `[[left, bottom], [right, top]]`. Here, the arrow head is at the top left, and tail is bottom right. So we can draw two lines to visually mark these. Replacing that section in your code with this:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
dl = 0.01 # some arbitrary length for the marker line
head = [leader_line_box.T[0][0], leader_line_box.T[1][1]]
line_head = Line2D([head[0],head[0]+dl], [head[1],head[1]+dl],
    transform=fig.transFigure, lw=2, color='r') # mark head with red
ax.add_line(line_head)

tail = [leader_line_box.T[0][1], leader_line_box.T[1][0]]
line_tail = Line2D([tail[0],tail[0]+dl], [tail[1],tail[1]+dl],
    transform=fig.transFigure, lw=2, color='g') # mark tail with green
ax.add_line(line_tail)
```

results in the following plot:

[image: plot with arrow head and tail marked]