# Cannot get the correct coordinate of text bounds in a matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, textbox

I am trying to get the coordinate of the actual text rendered by a `text` element in a figure

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.draw()
txt = plt.text(0, 0, ' THE SUPERMARKET CHAIN  SHUT DOWN  BECAUSE  OF  POOR MANAGEMENT', alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

From eyeballing the image the xlim is around [0, 1.1] and the ylim is around [0, .05]

I tried to get the coordinate based on this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267733/getting-the-coordinates-of-a-matplotlib-annotation-label-in-figure-coordinates) but neither of the textbox generated matches the estimated lims above. What am I doing wrong here?

```
txtbox = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform(txt.get_window_extent())
txtbox2 = matplotlib.text.Text.get_window_extent(txt)
print(txtbox)  ##[[0.125      0.10375   ][0.9703125  0.13291667]]
print(txtbox2) ##Bbox(x0=80.0, y0=49.8, x1=621.0, y1=63.8)
```

Comment: What you get back in the first case are figure coordinates. In the second case pixels.   It seem you want data coordinates, `ax.transData.inverted()...`

Comment: That was it thank you. If you'd like to make your comment an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest another question. Is there a way to fix the text size then change the ylim xlim? The purpose of getting the text bounds was so I can then change the ylim and xlim of the plot to match the txt size but when i do that the text just stays the same pixel size.

Comment: The text size is in points. Per default it's 10pt. And it stays 10pt, no matter how large or small the axes or figure.

Comment: I see, if that's the case I'll probably just find the ratio of pixel to axes' data coordinate then set the size of the text based on the ratio. Thanks for your help.